# Error bubbling errors on Collection in Symfony2 still shows in parent form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've tried to remove the error bubbling for the past few hours or day, and I just can't figure out why the errors stays in the parent form type.

```
->add('merchantAccounts', 'collection', array(
     'type'          =>  new MerchantAccountType(),
     'allow_add'     =>  true,
     'allow_delete'  =>  true,
     'by_reference'  =>  false,
     'error_bubbling' => false,
```

I've added error_bubbling almost anywhere else possible, still nothing...

Also here's a validation violation that shows in the parent form type, first argument does nothing.
MerchantNumber is a field in MerchantAccountType

```
$this->context->addViolationAt('merchantNumber', 'error.invalid_bank');
```

And the FormType calling MerchantAccountType

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Merchant',
        'error_bubbling' => false
));
```

Any help would be much appreciated :) thx!

Answer (score 0):

OK!

I've finally found out where the issue came from. I was running php 5.3.5 .
I installed 5.3.10 and it's finally working now!

So there's some magic happening between 5.3.6 and 5.3.10

Hope this might help someone one day!